# Can Kendo Datepicker be left open while scrolling the page?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, datepicker, telerik

By design, when a user scrolls the page, the datepicker's popup is closed automatically.

Is it possible for Kendo Datepicker to change this behavior?
It doesn't seem that [`option`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#fields-options) object has relevant properties.

PS. I'm asking because we have strange behavior of Kendo Datepicker automatically closes itself on the first click, after that everything works fine. I suspect it may be caused by page scrolling on datepicker open event.

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago I was solving very similar problem, just with different component but I believe that main idea of it can help you as well.

Scenario is that I blocked component from closing and enabled it based on condition. (Like value was selected etc.)

In your case, you probably will have to use *close* event, where you can easily block closing with

```
if (...) {
    el.preventDefault();
}
```

It is shown on this [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AKuQi/3)

Now you need some condition which will determine if datepicker can be closed like if there is selected value which can be something like on [this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AKuQi/4)

I am sure you will have to do some modifications, but I hope that atleast idea helps..